# @Autowired Constructor Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a class named as PoeticJuggler which has two constructors as follows:

```
 @Autowired(required=false)
    public PoeticJuggler(Sonnet29 poem)
    {
        super();
        this.poem=poem;
        System.out.println("Test to all");
    }

    @Autowired(required=false)
    public PoeticJuggler(TestConstJuggler tst)
    {
        super();
        this.poem=new Sonnet29();
        System.out.println("Test to Test Juggler");
    }
public PoeticJuggler(int beanBags,Poem poem)
    {
        super(beanBags);
        this.poem=poem;
    }
```

And the configuration file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
<context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="duke" class="com.springinaction.springidol.beans.Juggler">
        <constructor-arg value="15"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="sonnet29" class="com.springinaction.springidol.beans.Sonnet29">
    </bean>

    <bean id="testDuke" class="com.springinaction.springidol.beans.TestConstJuggler">
    </bean>

    <bean id="poeticDuke" class="com.springinaction.springidol.beans.PoeticJuggler">
    </bean>

    <bean id="theStage" class="com.springinaction.springidol.beans.Stage" factory-method="getInstance">
    </bean>
</beans>
```

When i run the following code:

```
public class BeanContext 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws PerformanceException 
{
ApplicationContext ctx=new  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("performancebean.xml");
Performer performer=(Performer)ctx.getBean("poeticDuke");
performer.perform();
}
}
```

i get the output as:

Test to Test Juggler
   JUGGLING 3 BEANBAGS

My confusion is that how spring is identifying which constructor to call, as both of the mentioned constructors are getting satisfied.

Comment: Does Spring always pick the same constructor if you run it multiple times?

Comment: Yes Mac. It always pics up the same constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to simulate the use case, to me it purely depends upon the order of constructors  returns by the reflection when multiple constructors getting satisfied. try the below in the beanContext and let us know the order. 
Note** There is no grantee that reflection returns the order as its presents in code.

```
Constructor<MainClass>[] methods = <yourClass>.class.getConstructors();
    for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
        Class<?>[] types = methods[i].getParameterTypes();
        System.out.println("Constructor "+i);
        for (int j = 0; j < types.length; j++) {
            System.out.println("Param Type" + types[j].getName());
        }
    }
```

UPDATE: 
    To understand more clearly find the sorting logic found in AutoWireUtils.sortConstructors . this method being called once the spring get all constructors using the below line

```
candidates = (mbd.isNonPublicAccessAllowed() ?
                        beanClass.getDeclaredConstructors() : beanClass.getConstructors());
```

AutoWireUtils.sortConstructors

```
public static void sortFactoryMethods(Method[] factoryMethods) {
    Arrays.sort(factoryMethods, new Comparator<Method>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Method fm1, Method fm2) {
            boolean p1 = Modifier.isPublic(fm1.getModifiers());
            boolean p2 = Modifier.isPublic(fm2.getModifiers());
            if (p1 != p2) {
                return (p1 ? -1 : 1);
            }
            int c1pl = fm1.getParameterTypes().length;
            int c2pl = fm2.getParameterTypes().length;
            return (new Integer(c1pl)).compareTo(c2pl) * -1;
        }
    });
}
```

So , it is purely based on Sort , in case both constructors has same weight then it is matter of how reflection returns the constructors.

Comment: @Mani.. I found this this out. If you remove the last constructor i get   **"Test to all"**     as Output, if not then    **"Test to Test Juggler"**     as the output.

This is the output of your code:

`Constructor 0
Param Typeint
Param Typecom.springinaction.springidol.interfaces.Poem
Constructor 1
Param Typecom.springinaction.springidol.beans.TestConstJuggler
Constructor 2
Param Typecom.springinaction.springidol.beans.Sonnet29`

But output is always constant unless you change the order of Constructors in the Class.

Comment: @Mani.. I think this is the pattern:  
`- If any non annotated constructor is present constructors are read in reverse order.   
- If not then in the natural order.`

Answer (score 0):

In this situation Spring identifies the proper bean by constructor parameter type.

When Spring performs autowiring and finds that

```
@Autowired(required=false)
public PoeticJuggler(Sonnet29 poem) {
...
```

it reads its constructor parameter type `com.springinaction.springidol.beans.Sonnet29`. Then it determines that there is only one bean with such a class in the context so it instantiates `sonnet29` bean first then instantiates `poeticDuke` passing reference to `sonnect29` as concstuctor arg.

Comment: @Evgen.. Can you be please more elaborate. Since argument types for both the Constructors are getting satisfied how did Spring identify which one to pick.

Config has both:
- Sonnet29
- TestConstJuggler

So why TestConstJuggler and not Sonnet29

Comment: @Evgen.. That's my point buddy.. It never calls Constructor having Sonnet29 as an argument.. If you look at the output, it's sysout of 2nd Constructor which does not have Sonnet29 but TestConstJuggler. My point is documentation says that if more than one constructor is getting satisfied by the Context then Constructor with highest no. of args being satisfied will be considered, but if both have same number of args, Spring should throw an error.